# How to convert str time to timestamp?

Tags: python, time, timestamp

I have a string `"15:15:00"`
I need to convert it to timestamp like `1410748201`

Python

Comment: What does `1410748201` represent?

Comment: Just the example of random timestamp

Comment: timestamp means nothing without a year and a date. This question doesn't make a lot of sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **UNIX timestamp** always needs a relation between a date and a time to actually form it, since it is the number of seconds that are passed since 1970-01-01 00:00. Therefore I would recommend you to use the `datetime` module.

Let's assume you have given the following format: "2022-10-31 15:15:00".
With `datetime` you can convert the string into a `datetime` object by using the `strptime()` function.
Afterwards, a `datetime` object gives you the ability to convert your datetime into a **UNIX timestamp** with the `timestamp()` method of your `datetime` object.

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_str = "2022-10-31 15:15:00"
datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(datetime_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print(datetime_obj.timestamp())
```